# How to loop run an executable multiple time without waiting for it to finish

Tags: bash

I have an executable (let's call it run) that takes a text file as an input. To run the code, I would do something like ./run file0.txt. In general, I have quite a number of txt files, so I would like to automate this process using bash script instead of doing ./run file_.txt about 60 times. Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

counter=0
for i in /directory/where/input/files/are/file{0..65..1}.txt
do
  cd /some/dir/for/out/files/outputs/
  mkdir file$counter
  cd file$counter
  /dir/where/executable/located/./run $i
  counter=$((counter+1))
done
```

What I'm trying to do with this script is as follows:

1. Go to a directory that will hold all of the output files
2. Make a directory for each specific input file
3. Go to that directory
4. Do ./run while being inside of that directory so that the output file will be made there

At the moment, the script seems to do what I want. However, the loop seems to be stuck at each iteration until the execution is finished. What I want is to run multiples of the execution at the same time. So, if I was to do this manually, the process would be something like:

a) mkdir file{0..65..1}

b) cd file0/

c) /dir/where/executable/located/./run file0.txt

d) cd ../file1/

e) /dir/where/executable/located/./run file1.txt

f) repeat d and e

How should I change my script to do that?

Note: I am still relatively new to bash scripting, so I know this may be somewhat crude. If there are ways to do what I want more efficiently, please suggest it to me.

Comment: And what does that have to do with c++?!? To start background processes from bash add a `&` after the command.

Comment: Included it out of habit. My bad!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash executes foreground processes in a synchronous way. To do it as you want, you have to **launch the process in the background** using `&`, as pointed out in the comments. You can make a function that implements the desired behavior for a file and then call it inside the loop.

The only problem with a separate asynchronous function, is that the `counter` variable will not necessarily match your actual numbered filenames, so if you want them to keep the original number, you  must extract it explicitly from the original name, or use an explicit variable. I will use the second approach in the following snippet:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Function to encapsulate your processing
# First arg: input file
# Second arg: counter
process_file(){
  cd /some/dir/for/out/files/outputs/
  mkdir file$2
  cd file$2
  /dir/where/executable/located/./run $1
}


for i in {0..65..1} # Iterate through the numbers, not the files, so we can use $i as a counter
do
  input_file=/directory/where/input/files/are/file$i.txt
  process_file $input_file $i & # Ampersand to launch in the background
done
```

---

*Edit:*
This is actually overkill for this case, as I'm pretty sure having you very same script, but with `&` appended to your `run` command, would do it. However, this approach is scalable in case you want to add more sequential processing for each single file and still have it in parallel for all files.